# OpenCV resize issue not working properly

Tags: python

```
    import tensorflow as tf        
   `import os`       
   `import numpy as np`        
   `import os, glob, cv2`        
    import os.path        
    import sys, argparse

    dir_path= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("cat2.jpeg"))        
    image_path = sys.argv[1]        
    filename = os.path.join(dir_path, image_path)        
    image_size = 128       
    num_channels = 3        
    images = []        

    image = cv2.imread(filename)        
    image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    ...


error Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c0a159fd3a64> in <module>()
      1 # resizing the image
----> 2 image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
      3 images.append(image)
      4 images = np.array(images, dtype= np.uint8)
      5 images = images.astype('float32')

error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1485299292920/work/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3492: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize
```

I've looked at other similar posts and tried to debug this error. Can anyone point out how to get rid of this error by looking at the above code? Is this some internal problem or there is some issue with the code?

Comment: i m not able to reproduce the error, your code works absolutely perfect for me. Try to print and check the values of dir_path and filename on the console

Comment: Yeah, the paths its printing are correct. I am running this code in a jupyter notebook inside an anaconda virtual environment. I installed opencv using this command - conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3.

Comment: what does image.shape return?